# What is the difference between nesting a Drawer navigator inside a Stack navigator, or the opposite?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In the documentation for version 6.x of React Navigation, in fundamentals,  [Navigating to a screen in a nested navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator), they have an example of nesting a Drawer navigator inside of a Stack navigator.

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={Root}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Why is it shown like this and not the Drawer as the parent navigator and the Stack inside?

I've seen [other](https://dev.to/easybuoy/combining-stack-tab-drawer-navigations-in-react-native-with-react-navigation-5-da) examples that do this (Drawer parent, Stack inside) but I don't understand what the difference in terms of layouts or the final UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked somewhere else and got this answer:

> If stack is nested inside drawer - you can still open drawer in any
> stack screen, etc 
> if drawer is nested inside stack - drawer will be
> only present in the screen that drawer is, and cannot be seen as other
> screens will render above it

Comment: If possible, could you post a link to the source of your information? If that's not possible, would you atleast details about the source to give proper credit, and allow us to verify.

Comment: @ouflak I don't have a link because I asked in this discord `reactiflux`. It's the one that is on the React Navigation page. I asked in the #help-react-native channel if I'm not mistaken